# One button works, one doesn't in jQuery.

Tags: jquery, html, css

Two buttons are created in the original HTML code.

```
<div class=ex>
    <button class=showprice>Show</button>
    <button class=hideprice>Hide</button>
    <table class=hideprice>
    ... rest of table.
```

Here's the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button.showprice').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('showprice')) {
            $(this).removeClass('showprice');
            $(this).addClass('hideprice');
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('hideprice');
            $(this).siblings().addClass('showprice');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('hideprice');
            $(this).addClass('showprice');
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('showprice');
            $(this).siblings().addClass('hideprice');
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/sgbotsford/MzuE9/1/

In the example instead of show and hide, I've done red and blue so that it's clearer what's happening.  In the working one they would tagged display:none and display:inherit instead.

Now what I expected to happen was that clicking on either button would cause the show and hide (red and blue) to reverse. Further, I would expect that clicking on a hide (red) button wouldn't work because it wouldn't match the button.showprice selector.   What *does* happen is that only the first button works, it it will work when both both red and blue.  If I change button.showprice to just button, then both buttons will work.  It is acting as if the function doesn't pick up that the matching of buttons and selectors has changed.

I'm missing a concept here.  Please enlighten me.

Comment: This may be a bit obvious but, It's *much* better to encase attributes in quotations, e.g. `<button class=showprice>` to `<button class="showprice">`

Comment: Because you are dynamically changing the elements you would need to rebind the event, or use the $(window).on.... technique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are only binding to `showprice` button

Use

```
$('button.showprice, button.hideprice').click(function () {
```

instead of

```
$('button.showprice').click(function () {
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MzuE9/2/)

Event is binded with an identifier element. i.e. *button with showprice class*. After event is binded event, even if you change class event will be associated with that element.

In [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MzuE9/4/), I have removed class showprice but event is still binded. Though I add *showprice* to second button event will not be binded with second button

Comment: Your idea would work, but it doesn't explain my knowledge gap.  Why does button 1 work the second time when it no longer has the class of showprice?  The idea is that I have two different buttons, only one of which is visible at a time.  I'm trying to understand.  Initially only button 1 shows (class showprice)  When it's clicked the state of both buttons and the table flips, so that button 1 is now class hideprice.

Comment: Binding.  Ok.  Will look up binding.  Is there a way to make the function state aware?

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford, I have tried to explain with an example. Please ping me if that doesn't help

Comment: Good answer.  I was totally unaware of binding.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need two buttons.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn ">Hide</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        $(this).text($(this).text() == "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide"); 
        $(this).siblings().toggleClass('showprice hideprice');
    });
});
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/MzuE9/6/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/MzuE9/5/

You'll want to use `.on` with this. when the DOM loads, it will only play with the objects that are defined. So when you tell it to watch for `click` actions on `button.showprice`, it will only listen for clicks on the object that has that selector when the dom is loaded.

`.on` will listen, no matter what changes.